# What is the unit of `Power_On_Hours` in `smartctl`?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, storage

Macbook Pro, OS: `10.13.6 (17G65)`

**9 days ago**, my [smartctl](https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/smartmontools/smartctl.8.in)'s output:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x000f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1638
```

**9 days later**, today's output:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x000f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1644
```

The macbook has been on from about 9:00 to about 22:00 everyday. The value from `1644 - 1638 = 6`, it's definitely not `hour`, so what is it?

Edited:

If the smartctl's result in MacOS is incorrect, can anyone suggest me another tool which can check the correct harddrive's power on time? Thanks.

Comment: Consider [asking a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for alternative tool recommendations, otherwise I suspect the edited additional question will be lost.

Comment: I have a suspicion that the unit is actually hours and everything is correct. Even if the MacBook Pro is powered on, the disk itself need not be powered on. If it is idle for a period of time, it is by default automatically powered down.

Answer (score 1):

## SMART Monitoring Tools

The [`smartctl`](https://www.smartmontools.org/browser/trunk/smartmontools/smartctl.8.in) tool claims hours, so that suggests one or more of the following:

1. A fault in the tool;
2. A fault in your drive reporting firmware;
3. Or that your drive was only *active* for six hours during that period.

Drives will power up and down whenever they can to save energy. Six hours of storage access may not be unrealistic but it all depends on how the computer is used.

Try using the `-v` flag to customise the output. You can specify times in minutes or other units. This may give a better insight into the reported values.

If you need help using and understand the results of `smartctl`, please [contact the developers](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Help). They are best placed to provide authoritative answers.

Comment: I thought I stated clearly that I mean 9 days, not a single day. And I am a programmer, I keep compiling code during the 9 days. cheers.

Comment: I tried `-v 9,minutes` and it shows `Power_On_Minutes 27h+24m`. This is really wrong. This is 2014 macbook pro. It can't be 27h for the ssd's life.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the number of days. Have you logged a bug with the developers of the tool?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I haven't filed a bug and don't plan to. Different manufacturer has different algorithm. I don't think anyone will fix it. The unit is just some magic number which the manufacturer may understand. :)